# "поверхове уявлення" чи "поверхневе уявлення"?

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами, терміни

Знайшла значення у словнику слова "поверховий", воно має два варіанти: 1-той, що має поверхи; 2-неглибокий;
А значення "поверхневе" - той що перебуває, здійснююється біля поверхні...
Зустрічала обидва варіанти, тоді як правильно вживати у контексті слова "уявлення"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/poverkhovyj) знаджу таке пояснення:

> ПОВЕРХОВИЙ 2, а, е. 1,. рідко. Те саме, що поверхневий. Вся ділянка під будівництво спланована з урахуванням відводу поверхових вод (Архітектура і будівництво, 4, 1955, 23).
>
> ПОВЕРХНЕ́ВИЙ, а, е. Який розміщується, перебуває, відбувається і т. ін. на поверхні чи недалеко від поверхні чого-небудь.
>
> У сільській місцевості для забезпечення водою потрібно використовувати підземні джерела, де води вищої якості порівняно з поверхневими (Хлібороб України, 8, 1969, 27).

Тобто саме у цьому значенні поняття будуть тотожними.

Проте щодо самого контекту, що Ви подаєте, то на сайті [Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/poverhoviy-i-poverhneviy) пишуть, що правильно "поверхове уявлення":

> Спілкування у соцмережах дає поверхові уявлення про людину. А поверхневими бувають джерела.